# Macro latency issue after inserting formulas - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, latency

I have a central database in `Excel` that uses specific values entered into `Column B` and hides/unhides other relevant `Columns` based on this value. This worked fine until I put in separate formulas that copy the different values into their respective `sheets`.

E.g. if `A` was entered in `Column B` it would should `Columns D:E`. A separate `formula` would then copy the `row` into a separate `sheet` that contained all the `A's`.

The issue is this macro is now taking a long time to perform. I've disabled the formulas to make them run manually but it doesnt help. Here is an example of the macro that hides/unhides Columns.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim t As Range
        For Each t In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
            Select Case (t.Value)
                Case "A"
                    Columns("B:BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("H:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("AF:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Case "B"
                    Columns("B:BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:G").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("P:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Case "C"
                    Columns("B:BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("T:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Case "D"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("E:S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("AB:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BN:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Case "E"
                    Columns("B:BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("D:AB").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("AF:BO").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Case "F"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("E:AE").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("AN:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "G"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:BJ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BL:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "H"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:BJ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BL:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "I"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "J"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("E:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "K"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "L"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "M"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "N"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("E:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "O"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:BJ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BM:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "P"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:AM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("AO:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "Q"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "R"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("AP:BM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "S"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:AO").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("AQ:BM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "T"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:AN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("AP:BM").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "U"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:AP").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BB:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                 Case "V"
                    Columns("B:BP").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Columns("F:BA").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BK:BN").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True 
                    'do nothing
            End Select
        Next t
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100 '<<<
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

This is the formula:

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX('XXXXX'!B$5:B$9963,MATCH($A5,'XXXXX'!$A$5:$A$9963,0)),"")="","",INDEX('XXXXX'!B$5:B$9963,MATCH($A5,'XXXXX'!$A$5:$A$9963,0)))
```

The database contains around 3000 rows. The file size is approx 7-8MB. I've removed all the formulas but the same latency exists. I removed 2000 rows of data and this made it quicker. But it doesnt seem like a large amount to make that much of a difference?

The file is shared through OneDrive with numerous users using it in real-time. A user has since mentioned he cannot open the file at all. It crashes upon opening. Could it be a coincidence and a broken link is causing a corruption?

Comment: what are the formulas you use for copying data?

Comment: @teylyn updated

Comment: If you suspect that your files are getting corrupted I recommend to try the binary format `xlsb` which results in smaller files and seems to be much more stable than the open XML format `xlsm`. Worth a try (I personally had many issues with bigger files, `xlsm` and file corruption in a normal daily use).

Comment: @JPA0888 Please test what happens if you replace the complete code in this event by just this line `MsgBox "I run"`. Is it still slow then? If yes this means your formula is slow in general and has nothing to do with the code itself. So actually the cell change you made caused the formula to re-calculate. So the re-calcuation comes before the VBA event and that's why it looks to be slow (but actually it's just the formula being slow).

Comment: @JPA0888 Does the formula that you showed depend on cells that have formulas themseves? In this case these formulas might be the issue of slowing down. If so please show them too in your question ([edit]).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, I removed all formulas and it was the same speed. I removed around 2000 rows and it was much quicker. Just for reference, there's about 10 values that are used to hide/undihe various columns.

Comment: @Peh, I've added all the values. Do you think this can be more efficient still?

Comment: @JPA0888 I wasn't asking to remove the formulas instead **keep all the formulas** and test what happens if you **replace the complete code in this event** by just this line `MsgBox "I run"`. Is that slow too? • Are there formulas in in column A or B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can reduce your code to only one `Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))` and kick out the loop and use the `Match` function instead. This way you will only hide the column once and not *every time* a value `A` appears in the affected range.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) 'intersect olny once and set into variable for re-use

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo safe_exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        Dim FoundAt As Long
        On Error Resume Next
        FoundAt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("A", AffectedRange, False)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If FoundAt <> 0 Then
            Columns("B:BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Columns("H:AD").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("AF:BL").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Columns("BQ").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If

        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100 '<<<
    End If

safe_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```